# How to address a professional contact made a year ago?

Tags: communication, networking, switzerland

I need to send an email to a contact I've made a year ago while traveling. I've met this person by popping up on the company and asking if "someone could talk to me."

I have interest in working for them and would like to drop a notice now (a month to my travel) to see if I could get to know more people there and specially if they manage to receive me in a more structured way so I get to talk a bit with some of the technical guys.

How should I approach this situation?

**Adding more info:**

Hello jmac thanks for the reply, I have not sent many messages for this person. The person is indeed located in another country, she is based in Switzerland while I'm in Brazil.
How did I met this person... A year ago I've seen an announce in LinkedIn inviting people to do judo and work in Switzerland. As I've previously lived in Germany and know some German I thought of it as a good chance to change airs. So I decided to see which company offer jobs positions in that area. I came to know they have a Microeletronics Center in this location. I've tried many times to contact them by phone and email with no luck. So I decided to just show up and see if someone could talk to me.

Of course I was received and people where kind to me. But I could not do the next step which would be hired. So I set as a goal for the past year to improve my CV, I did courses learned new technologies made a paper publication in a decent conference. Hence I have "new things to show".

As pointed before the important things is to get the person on the right mindset and this is what I'm attempting to achieve. I proper dropped email before I arrive can avoid the rushes from my last arrival while given a much better impression of my compromise in get where I want to (i.e. get a job position)

Comment: How does this related to productivity?

Comment: By addressing people properly I maximize my time scoping for jobs also I make their time more productive.

Comment: You asked if something is proper.  That means the question is more about customs and etiquette than productivity.  Luckily there is a SE site called workplace.  I'll move your question there.

Comment: Hello vfbsilva, and welcome to The Workplace! Would you mind adding a little more details for us? Have you been in contact with this person the entire year? Is this in a different location than you are in (different country perhaps)? Could you add a bit more detail about how you met this person (you really showed up at his/her company, and they were the person you talked to)? The best questions here ask questions that inspire answers of *how* or *why*, so focusing the question may help get you better answers. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Yes they are on the same company. I'm not sure if they hold the same position. Yes the person was related to hiring she was responsible for setting up the operations in Brazil and assembling the teams.

Answer (score 4):

So, you briefly met someone and want to send them a message. I find that the key to 'random' emails is to get in the right mindset. I bet this connection is important in the company and that sense he/she is important they receive many 'random' emails a day from people. They get all these emails, but you are a step ahead because your email isn't completely random. You have met them before, so here is how I would right it.

Hello [First Name],
I'm interested in [whatever you want] because I'm [why you would be good for the position]. We met in [wherever you were when you met] and I learned [something you learned] from our conversation. I'm applied it to my [life/career]. Could we [whatever you want - ex: meet, talk, interview].

Hope this helps.

FYI: I'm an American, so your formatting may be slightly different. The key is to get his/her attention with what you want and then quickly remind him/her who you are.